# How can a (Firefox) WebExtension know its own version?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm porting a legacy Firefox extension to WebExtensions.  I want to know at run time the version number of the extension itself.  Right now I'm doing:

```
let extensionVersion = (function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.overrideMimeType('application/json');
  xhr.open('GET', browser.extension.getURL('manifest.json'), false);
  xhr.send(null);
  var manifest = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  return manifest.version;
})();
```

This dirty hack which relies on synchronous XHR.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a dedicated function for retrieving the manifest:

```
browser.runtime.getManifest().version
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/getManifest

Comment: Thank you.  I've got issues with the wiki/organization version of Mozilla's documentation.  So not discoverable.  I explicitly looked for a method to give me this and didn't find it.